# Is there a way to notify specific users when new posts are published to specific pages?

Tags: posts, custom-field, notifications

New to wordpress! I tried searching but couldn't quite find a duplicate question..

Upon having users register, I have created custom fields collecting unique meta data of the users(such as instruments they play, what genre of music they like, etc.).

There are multiple pages on my website dedicated to different genres (jazz, pop, rock, etc.) and each of those pages have child pages with instruments (piano, drums, trumpet).

How would I notify users with the meta data of instrument: "trumpet" and genre: "jazz" whenever a post is made on either the jazz page or its trumpet child page.

I tried searching for plug-ins but no such luck...the best I can find is ["Better notifications for WordPress"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/). It is able to filter users by meta data, but it notifies then for all instances of an action (I can only notify instrument: "trumpet" and genre: "jazz" users for ALL new posts published...not for particular pages.)

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!